# Where do I put the inversion counter in this merge sort algorithm?

Tags: c++, mergesort, inversion

I am trying to count the number of inversions that occur during the merge sort progress of a 100,000 integer array. The values in the array are in no particular order. My question is simple, where in the merge sort algorithm would I apply the inversion counter? Below if the merge sort algorithm by itself, and the image after that is where I propose putting the inversion counter. The file reads correctly and the merge sort works correctly, I am only asking if my placement of the inversion counter is accurate. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**I have edited the page to only include the merge function**

```
 void merge(vector<int> &left, vector<int> &right, vector<int> &array, int &inversionCount) 
{
    int leftSize = left.size();
    int rightSize = right.size();
    int i = 0, l = 0, r = 0;

    while (l < leftSize && r < rightSize)
    {
        if (left[l] < right[r])
        {
            int temp1 = l;
            while ((right[r] > left[temp1]) && temp1 < left.size() - 1)
            {
                inversionCount++;
                temp1++;
            }
            array[i] = left[l];
            i++;
            l++;
        }
        else if (right[r] < left[l])
        {
            int temp1 = r;
            while ((left[l] > right[temp1]) && temp1 < right.size() - 1)
            {
                inversionCount++;
                temp1++;
            }
            array[i] = right[r];
            i++;
            r++;
        }
        else
        {
            array[i] = right[r];
            i++;
            r++;
        }
    }

    while (l < leftSize)
    {
        array[i] = left[l];
        i++;
        l++;
    }
    
    while (r < rightSize)
    {
        array[i] = right[r];
        i++;
        r++;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have realized that the inversion counter should at the very least be in the merge sort function and not the merge function, I apologize and will edit it

Comment: *I am trying to count the number of inversions that occur during the merge sort progress of a 100,000 integer array* -- Start with an array of 5 or 10 items, and count the inversions manually, on paper.  Then see if where you placed your inversion counter matches what you did on paper.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In my case, on paper, any time the right hand number was less than the left, an inversion happened. So, that makes me assume that the inversion counter should only increment when right[r] < left[l] in the merge function, which leaves me with 776,644 inversions. This doesn't sound too far off for this many values, but I still feel as if I am forgetting something

Comment: The point of trying a smaller sample set is it makes it easier to debug.  If the hand-calculation using a small a sample, assuming it is correct, doesn't match what the program is producing, then start with that.  It makes no sense trying 100,000 items if 10 items doesn't work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Okay so it worked with one set of values but not a different set, darn. Does it go from left to right all the way through? The values I just tested were 12, 13, 40, 25, 17, 12, 10 which has 13 inversions from left to right. But my code said there were only seven. I am sorry for being dumb lol, but does this have to do with how merge sort works?

Comment: `if (left[l] < right[r])` -- Isn't this where an "inversion" occurs?  If you mean "inversion" to be "swapping items", then this would be the obvious place (and also the `else` portion would be the second place).

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, it sounds like you're on the right track.

However, let's look at a case of some random numbers, and skip the first few merges. We'll take the case of left[4,5,7,8,9] and right[1,2,3,5,6]. Perhaps some inversions have already been counted, but we'll just start here.

First, we check whether left[4] is greater than right[1]. It is, so we must increment our inversion counter. However, [4] is also greater than [2] and [3] in this case, and that must also be accounted for.

The question is, how can we do that? Well, when we realize than [4] is greater than [1], we can start another loop, inside the right array, incrementing our inversion counter until we encounter a value greater than or equal to 4, and at that point we stop. So in this case, we go +1 for [4] against [1], [2], and [3], and then we stop at right[5]. This leaves us with +3, and then we put down 4 in the new array, and start over with left[5], counting back up again.

Obviously we must save the index of right[1] before we begin this check, or else the MergeSort algorithm might get screwed up.

This is a naive approach though, since there is really no reason to count all the way back up when we look at left[5], since we know that left[5] > left[4], and we already know that left[4] was greater than several values in the right[] array. For something like 100,000 values, this naivety may cause your program to slow down quite a bit.

Comment: does placing the inversion counter in the two if statements inside the while loop inside the merge algorithm make sense?

Comment: I have edited the merge function, how does this look?

Comment: It looks good! However, why would we need the loop you built in the left[l] < right[r] case?

Comment: I thought that I needed both sides of it, would I still increment the inversion counter at all? Because it currently returns a lower value than intended. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not completely sure what you may be missing. However, in your loop you write "temp1 < right.size() - 1". This should simply be "temp1 < right.size()" or, equivalently, "temps <=  right.size() - 1".

Comment: If i dont have it as explicitely temp1 < right.size() -1 then the compiler crashes and asks me to abort

Comment: Actually, I see what may be going wrong. In fact, I overcomplicated it a bit. Look at the example left = [1,1,3,4] and right = [1,2,5,7]. Since left is less than right for the first two iterations, we can pop off the first two elements of left and now have something like left = [3,4] and right = [1,2,5,7]. Now, we see that right[1] < both left[3] AND left [4]. In fact, right[1] is certainly less than EVERY element that remains in the left array, after the already popped ones, so we can increment by the whatever length still remains of left.

Comment: which would only happen when the right side is greater than the left side i.e inversionCount += leftSize - 1. The only problem with that is that it still gives me 6 inversions when the answer is 9. This stuff is so confusing lol

Comment: @thedrooster -- From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c), the merge sort code as [implemented here](https://godbolt.org/z/7PxnPfxEY) shows that the result is 9 for the inversion count.  So it boils down to a "correct" implementation of `std::inplace_merge` that you are trying to write.  Or if not that, rewrite your code so that you call a function to determine if an element is placed before another, and in there, you increment the counter if the elements are out of order (see the `main` function and the lambda).